# Incorrect syntax near the keyword “AS” when alter trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-trigger

i created trigger called trgInsteadofdeleteEmp
and i just want to alter it, i wrote the following SQL code

```
alter trigger trgInsteadofdeleteEmp on Emp
instead of delete
as
begin
    declare @id int , @name nvarchar(100)
    select @id =id from deleted
    select @name = name from deleted
    insert into EmployeeAudit values (@id ,@name + 'tried to delete at' + GETDATE() as varchar(50))
end
```

and have the following output:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure trgInsteadofdeleteEmp, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

can someone point me in the direction of how to find the error

Thanks.

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement has a number of errors (missing `CAST`, concatenating datetime with string). Also, it is coded to handle only one row and triggers need to handle multiple rows,  Use INSERT...SELECT instead of INSERT...VALUES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no, no, no, no.

Don't make the mistake of assuming that `inserted` and `deleted` have only one row.  You are just putting errors in your code that are going to pop up at an unexpected time.  I actually wish that SQL Server flagged this usage when creating the trigger.

Instead:

```
alter trigger trgInsteadofdeleteEmp on Emp
    instead of delete
as
begin
    insert into EmployeeAudit(id, name)
        select id,
               name + ' tried to delete at ' + convert(varchar(255), GETDATE(), 121) )
        from deleted d;
end;
```

Your error is caused by the `as`.  There seems to be a missing `cast()` function.  But that is not the right fix.  With date/times, use `convert()` or `format()` along with the desired format.

Other suggestions:

- Always include the column names when doing an `insert`.  In fact, an audit table really should have an identity id column, `createdBy`, and `createdAt` columns, all with default values.
- Look at the strings that will be produced and be sure they are readable.
- Use semicolons to end statements.
- Don't rely on default formatting for date/time values.